# Some web elements are not renderred At All on when running selenium automated tests triggered by Jenkins for a webapp

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automation

Web elements that are of svg format (calendar icon) aren't rendered at all when tests are triggered by Jenkins. The same elements are displayed all the time if I check the same site on any browser manually, via local test on Intelij Idea or via CMD maven tests (mvn -clean test).

I do use waits and wait.until() and at times Thread.sleep() for at least 1 minute for the calendar icon to get displayed but again via jenkins, tests always fails due to NoSuchElementException since elements aren't rendered at all. I have tried looking for answers on as many forums I have seen but still can't find the solution

[Here's how the Graph looks on the webpage during jenkins triggered tests:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK2EX.png)

[Same graph when I manually check the site any time or run via localised tests (intellij and cmd):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDaqp.png)

[Here's how the calendar button looks on the webpage during jenkins triggered tests:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BORNG.png)

[Same calendar button when I manually check the site any time or run via localised tests (intellij and cmd):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgpUK.png)

Another important thing to note, this only happens on our work computer. It runs on Windows 8.1 and Chrome & Edge version 109
[Chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTe1h.png)
[Edge version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wMo0.png)

On my personal machine jenkins or not I don't experience this problem.
What could be the problem? Its been months without finding a solution and will be beoyond grateful if someone knows what could be the solution. Thanks

Selenium Automation Testing of a webapp. Tests are triggered periodically via Jenkins CI/CD platform

Comment: Guys I finally found the problem. It wasn't a Jenkins issue but a selenium issue. The website is mobile/tablet adaptation and sometimes Selenium webdriver opens the web app in Mobile view, not yet sure why but perhaps because the PC is old. To fix this I added a Chrome/Edge Option - option.addArguments("--force-device-scale-factor=1"); That argument forces the browser to always run tests in the PC's true resolution (its like a resolution lock) so not matter what webdriver doesn't glitch and sometimes open browser in a resolution that triggers mobile view